# sign of a function on given interval

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let
$$g(x)=y x \sin (\pi  x) \sin (y x)+\cos (y x) (\sin (\pi  x)+\pi  x \cos (\pi  x))-\pi  x-\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 \pi  x)$$
with  $y$ is constant, such that $$-\pi\le y\le \pi$$

Prove that  $ \;g(x)\le 0 \; $ in the interval $\; (0,\frac{1}{2}]$

Comment: Graph of $yx\sin(\pi x)\sin(yx)$ is bounded between the graph of $yx\sin(yx)$. And consequently $yx\sin(\pi x)\sin(yx)-\pi x\lt 0 \forall x\in (0,\pi/2]$ follows from the extreme case of $y$ being equal to $+\pi$.